# Error in Maurins proof for the nuclear spectral theorem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, nuclear-spaces, rigged-hilbert-spaces

I am currently studying the nuclear spectral theorem as presented in K. Maurins Monograph [2], second chapter or alternatively his paper [1] which contains basically the same proof.

Let $\Phi\subset H\subset \Phi'$ be a rigged Hilbert space, $\Phi$ nuclear. We want to prove, that there exists a complete set of generalized eigenfunctions in $\Phi'$.

The basic idea is the following: We use the Integral formulation of the Neumann spectral theorem, i.e. every normal operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$ is unitary equivalent to a multiplication operator on a direct integral of Hilbert Spaces (which is basically an $L^2$-type complex-valued function space), the latter shall be called $\hat{H}$ and the unitary transformation $F:\varphi\rightarrow \varphi(x)$. The key element in the proof is now, that we can prove, that evaluating some $F\varphi$ at a point of the spectrum, say $\lambda$, is a continuous mapping into the complex numbers and therefore associated with some element of the dual space. Concretely, Maurin "shows" that that the mapping $F(\lambda):\varphi\rightarrow\varphi(\lambda)$ is continuous for every $\lambda$ up to a set of measure zero.

**I highly dout that this mapping is even well-defined**, as the functions in the direct integral of Hilbert spaces are only defined up to an equivalence class, i.e. they can differ on a set of measure zero.

Am I overlooking something trivial? Is there a simple way to patch this up?
Is there some reference which solves this issue? I have heard that the proof given by Gelfand and Vilekin also has a similar issue.
I would greatly appreciate any help, I am very stuck at the moment.

**References**

[1] Krzysztof Maurin,"Allgemeine Eigenfunktionsentwicklungen. Spektraldarstellung abstrakter Kerne. Eine Verallgemeinerung der Distributionen auf Lieschen Gruppen". (German) Bulletin de l’Académie Polonaise des Sciences, Série des Sciences Mathématiques, Astronomiques et Physiques 7, 471-479 (1959), [MR114133](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=114133), [Zbl 0106.08903](https://zbmath.org/0106.08903).

[2] Krzysztof Maurin, *General eigenfunction expansions and unitary representations of topological groups*. (English)
Monografie Matematyczne. 48. Warszawa: PWN - Polish Scientific Publishers. 367 p. (1968), [MR247377](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=247377), [Zbl 0185.39001](https://zbmath.org/0185.39001).

Answer (score 12):

In [this discussion,](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=294488) there is a pointer to a paper by G. G. Gould (J. LMS, 1968) which supposedly gives a correct but hard to read proof.

This is the paper:
Gerald G. Gould, "[The spectral representation of normal operators on a rigged Hilbert space](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-43.1.745)". (English) Journal of the London Mathematical Society 43, 745-754 (1968), [MR0230148](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=230148), [Zbl 0159.43401](https://zbmath.org/0159.43401).

Comment: Thank you, this paper seems to resolve the question. The proof seems to be quite technical, but thats fine I guess. I am not sure whether I maybe have found a simpler solution, but I will proofread it first.

Comment: @Daniel If you found a simpler solution, be sure to keep us posted :)

Comment: @Daniel did you find a simpler solution?

Comment: Any update @Daniel

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps Vol 3 by Gel'fand and Shilov could be helpful here instead of Vol 4?

I. M. Gel’fand, G. E. Shilov, *[Generalized functions. Vol. 3. Theory of differential equations](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/chel-379)*. Translated from the Russian by Meinhard E. Mayer. Reprint of the 1967 original published by Academic Press. (English)
Providence, RI: AMS Chelsea Publishing (ISBN 978-1-4704-2661-3/hbk). pp. x+222 (2016), [MR3468845](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3468845), [Zbl 1339.01008](https://zbmath.org/1339.01008).

Gel'fand and Shilov take a slightly different approach there, deriving the generalized eigenfunctions as, essentially, a distributional derivative (in $\Phi'$) of the spectral projections $E_\lambda f$ of an arbitrary function $f\in H$. They then show completeness in the subspace $\{E_\lambda f\}_{\lambda}$ using some theory on the a.e. recovery of a function of bounded variation from its Radon-Nikodym derivative. The general case is handled by expressing $H$ as a direct sum of such subspaces.

There are many related constructions, because of the connection to wave-packets (in scattering) and the resolvent operator. See, e.g., the following paper

Nicolas A. Derzko, "[Generalized eigenfunctions and real-axis limits of the resolvent](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1972-0310684-1)", Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 174 (1972), 489-506 (1973), [MR0310684](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=310684), [Zbl 0221.47015](https://zbmath.org/0221.47015), (available also [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1996119)).